# Pythow write to txt file,my strings are overwritten by array

Tags: python, io

For example

```
import numpy as np

with open('new2.txt','w') as f:
    f.write('vel.1d\n')
    f.write('base.mod\n')

a1=np.empty(5)
a1.fill(2900)   

np.savetxt('new2.txt',a1,fmt='%4.1f')
```

But this is my new2.txt

```
2900.0
2900.0
2900.0
2900.0
2900.0
```

I need first to write strings,then do some calculations and write down the array.How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `with open('new2.txt','w') as f:` , the file is closed after you leave the `with` block, so `savetxt` overwrites from the beginning. You could do:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a1=np.empty(5)

In [3]: a1.fill(2900)

In [4]: with open('new2.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('vel.1d\n')
    f.write('base.mod\n')
    np.savetxt(f,a1,fmt='%4.1f')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
h = 'vel.1d\n' + 'base.mod\n' # prepare file header

np.savetxt('new2.txt', a1, fmt = '%4.1f', header = h) # use header
```

Comment: But what if I have to write two lines 100.0 0.25 100.0;
0.0 -0.375 -10.0 after the header and befor the array?